# Why Isn't This Model Data Loading Into Pages Controller Properly?

Tags: cakephp, model

I have a Model with data that I want to use to populate a "Recent XYZ" section on the homepage, which is controlled by the Pages controller.

In the Pages controller, I have the following code:

```
$this->loadModel('Model');
$this->set('datas', array($this->Model->find('all', array('limit' => 5))));
```

Then, in Home.ctp, I have tried to access the data via:

```
if(!empty($datas)) { foreach($datas as $data):
echo $data['0']['Model']['field'];
endforeach; }
```

I ran debug on the find('all') and it is returning an array, but I don't see anything wrong with my code. And I've tried using find('list') and find('first') and changin the $data['0']['Model']['field'] to $data['Model']['field'] when necessary as a result. But, it still gives an Undefined Index error for Model.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Is your loadModel code inside the index method?

Comment: It was inside of the display() method. I'll try moving it into the index() method and see if that works.

Comment: Ok, now it just shows a blank space.. not sure why..

Comment: Ok, this is happening because there is now $datas. This means that it must need to be in the display() method, but that's not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't put the numbered key if you're iterating over it with a foreach. So,

```
echo $data['0']['Model']['field'];
```

should be:

```
echo $data['Model']['field'];
```

**EDIT:** So, to clarify, if you are using `find('all')`, and iterating over the returned array with `foreach`, you would want `$data['Model']['field']`. If you were not iterating, but just wanted the first result, you would use `$data[0]['Model']['field']`. If you are using `find('first')`, you could just use `$data['Model']['field']`, and you would not want to use the `foreach` in this case.

So I'm a little confused by the context of this. You have copied the Pages controller into controllers directory, and put the above code within the `display()` method? What do you get when you put `pr($datas)` in `home.ctp`?

Comment: I tried it without the [0] as well before without avail. When I do the pr($reviews) it shows the initial array and then two array[0]'s before the array['model']. Weird?

Comment: Also, I have a pages_controller.php in the controllers folder (isn't that where it's supposed to be? I don't use a generator...) and then put the above code in the display() method, yes.

Comment: If you're getting the data you want in the array, then the only question is how you iterate over it and print the values you want. It should be pretty easy to figure out -- just reference actual keys in the array. You could even put `pr($data)` in your foreach loop, and see what the array looks like at that moment.